# Having trouble importing C# interface into Python

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, import, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I've been doing a bunch of searching and reading today, and haven't figured out the right way to implement something, or even determining if it's possible.

Here's the gist of what I'm attempting right now.  I have an application that loads plugins via MEF.  Plugins can implement a variety of interfaces, and let's say I have one called `IDevice`.  I had this wacky idea that maybe a user would want to write his own Device plugin in IronPython, and his IronPython would just have to inherit from `IDevice` and implement the requisite methods.

Now I know it's possible to implement the interface in IronPython by defining a class like this:

```
class MyDevice(IDevice):
  pass
```

But I can't get past the first problem -- what's the correct way to import the interface?

The IDevice interface is defined in a separate assembly called MyInterfaces.dll like this:

```
namespace Company.Shared.MyInterfaces
{
    public interface IDevice
    {
        string GetName();
    }
}
```

I've tried `import MyInterfaces` since that's the most logical thing, but that didn't work.  I also tried many less logical combinations of `import`s and `from`s.  I always get the following error:

```
ImportException occurred
No module named MyInterfaces
```

I loaded Process Monitor to see what my app was trying to load when I executed my script, and it was trying to load a file called MyInterfaces, and then would try to load MyInterfaces.py.  Well, the file is called MyInterfaces**.dll**, so I changed my import statement to read `import MyInterfaces.dll`, but that had no effect -- my code would still just try to load a file called MyInterfaces.  I have confirmed that all of my dependencies are in the right folder.

I feel super lame for not being able to figure this out, so I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the correct approach would be:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('MyInterfaces')

from Company.Shared.MyInterfaces import IDevice
```

Comment: ugh... I saw that used in a lot of the examples in the book, but it just didn't click for me.  I'll try that now, thanks!

Comment: No problem, hope it works... I know next to nothing about IronPython, but I'm a mean Googler.  :)

Comment: cripes I searched google like crazy but wasn't able to put it all together.  :'(  I don't think the book ever said that you *must* import clr in every script, but now I'll have to go back and re-read it!

Comment: I don't think you have to import clr, but nothing else gives you the ability to declare assembly references.